# what is the best design pattern to follow for creating a controller servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i want to know which is the best servlet pattern to follow for creating a controller servlet.

So far i am writing a controllerservlet like this for handling the requests

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = req.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equals("LOGIN")){


        }else if(action.equals("Deposit")) {

        }
        else if(action.equals("Withdraw")) {

        } else if(action.equals("view")) {

        }
}
```

is it ok to proceed like this or does anyone have a better approach for this?

this is my sample html:

```
<form action="Controller" method="post">
<center><br><br>
<h2><u><i><b>LOGIN SCREEN</b></i></u></h2><br><br><br>
<h4>Enter User Name :<input type=text name="userid" size=6 style="height:20;color=red"><br><br>
 User  Password &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp :<input type=password name ="pwd" size=20><br><br>
<h3>ARE  YOU A NEW USER? THEN REGISTER NOW.</H3>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="LOGIN">
<input type ="submit" name="login" value="login" >
<input type="button" value="register" onclick="reg()">
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: The best approach, IMHO, is to stop reinventing the wheel and use an action-based framework like Stripes of Spring MVC that does all this, and much more, for you, and supports several methods of selecting the appropriate action.

Comment: @adarshr. Yeah have to handle that

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself try to use Command pattern from 'Gang of Four'. You can put your commands in the Map with String keys. Then executing can be seem like: Command cmd = commandMap.get("action"); cmd.execute(req, resp);

Answer (score 3):

Maybe REST (like [RESTeasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html)) is of your interest if you can adjust the form's action:

```
public class Controller {

   @POST
   @Path("/login")
   public String doLogin() {...}

   @POST
   @Path("/view")
   public String showView() {...}  

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use one of the many already available frameworks to do that for you, you can start off with the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), combining it with the factory and null value object pattern. Thats just for starters.